# Should we burninate the [c-api] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-api) What's that tag? No description, seems as mistakenly entered to indicate API in C language, in which the "C" tag is enough.
 I last saw it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375218/how-to-disable-warnings-in-tensorflow-written-to-output-when-using-the-c-api-of) question.

Comment: For me it feels that example question is really not about `c` language, so it shouldn't be marked as `c` and c-api looks like a good fit.

Comment: Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow. Before burnination can proceed your question needs a bit more info on how the tag meets the burnination criteria. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: I added the burninate-request for this and edited reasons for why I believe it should be removed into my answer. There's currently 102 questions with the tag so we must use the formal burnination process. Otherwise I can help out removing it, but we'll have to wait for community consensus, featuring and all that jazz.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like something that is used a lot together with the Python and Tensorflow tags, for questions related to calling C code from another language. Perhaps the intention of [c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-api) is to avoid tagging a question with multiple language tags, which isn't appropriate if the question is actually just about one language.

However, browsing the posts with these tags, they most often include C code. Many of them are more about C than about Python. And many of them are about C++, not C. Etcetera. So it would seem that [c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-api)  is superfluous and kind of a "meta tag", since "C API" could mean anything.

Using multiple language tags is fine if your question is indeed about mixing languages or calling one language from another language. Most of these would be fine to tag with multiple language tags.

EDIT: as noted in comments, a better tag for the Python case already exists,  [python-c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-c-api). Use that one for the Python case specifically.

At some point I tried to get meta to establish rules for when it would be appropriate to use both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), since we traditionally have lots of problems with both of these tags being used for the same post. It boiled down to the cross-tagging policies found under tag usage in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). One appropriate situation when both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) should be used is when writing C++ code but using a C library. This is essentially the same situation.

---

Specifically, the tag meets the burnination criteria quite well:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is ambiguous and could mean any library.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It is something of a meta tag mostly describing what the question contains, not what it is about. By itself, the tag is too broad.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not really. It can only be used together with the appropriate library tag, and then the other tag (like Tensorflow, Win API etc) already means that the API is in C, implicitly.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

---

My proposed course of action is to burninate [c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-api) and replace it with the appropriate language tags:

- If the question is about writing an extension for Python using the C API, use [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [python-c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-c-api).
- If the question is about Python but contains C code, or if the OP needs help from a C programmer, tag with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) as well.
- Similarly if the question is about writing Python but contains C++ or the OP needs help from a C++ programmer, add [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
- If the question is about calling a C API from C++, tag with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
- If the question isn't actually about C but rather Tensorflow etc, keep the Tensorflow tag only.

And so on. That is, careful manual reviewing of each post as per [the process for tag removal (burnination)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

Comment: I would disagree with `Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?` part. For example `opencv` library has both c++ and c api (and even python) & c-api can be used in c++ code. So having `opencv` `c-api` tags would actually add meaningful information. I think that opencv is likely not the only library with that kind of api structure. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383179/how-does-cvpolylines-work) is example of question marked as opencv and c-api for which `c` tag won't fit because question is about c-api usage in c++.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. In case the language matters to the question, then you should tag it [tag:opencv] + [tag:c] (or [tag:c++]). In case it doesn't, you don't need to add a language tag. Otherwise we'll end up creating a "x-api" meta tag for every language that exists. The question you linked should be tagged [tag:opencv] + [tag:c] + [tag:c++], because it's about using a C library from C++ code.

Comment: while language matters - c++ - it is important to add information that c-api of certain library is used in this context. It can be salvaged if we have had something like `opencv-c-api`, but I would really not want to add extra tag if 2 tags combined can give all required information for many libraries.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Not everything the question contains need to be in the tags though. But in your specific example, the current policy is to use both C and C++ tags, regardless of whether the c-api tag exists or not.

Comment: Now that PHP 7.4 will introduce FFI I will assume we will be getting more questions tagged with `c-api` and `php`. This tag is as ambiguous as [tag:api]